# Convenient way to define many variables at once in R?

Tags: r

Basic question for a guy who is mostly new to programming/R: I want to define 100 variables, `x1`, `x2`, ..., `x100` where `xi = i^2`. I want to create these definitions so I can later use the variable names, not print the values. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This for-loop does what you request.

```
for (i in 1:100){
  assign(paste0("x", i), i^2)
}
```

However, creating 100 objects in the workspace may not be a good way to organize these objects. Another option is to create these 100 elements and store in a vector.

```
x_vec <- (1:100)^2
names(x_vec) <- paste0("x", 1:100) # Name the vector
```

After that, we can access the element based on name or index.

```
# Access by name
x_vec[["x10"]]
# [1] 100

# Access by index
x_vec[[10]]
# [1] 100
```

Comment: Glad to help. If either 42- and my answer are helpful, please consider to accept one of the post as the answer to your question so that others know this question has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally unwise to create many variables at once in the global environment. It will be difficult to access them or modify them programmatically. Instead create them in a list:

```
my_power_list <- setNames( as.list( (1:5)^2 ), paste0("x"), 1:100) )
```